# How to disable the Start button in Java Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, disabled-control

I am making a Desktop application using Java-Swing which is used to lock the desktop home screen.

I have used `JFrame` with Maximum size (as per Desktop resolution i.e. 1366x768).  I have already disable alt-f4 and alt-tab key pairs.
But how to disable Start button in keyboard?

Comment: *"But how to disable Start button in keyboard?"*  Java is not well suited to these types of very OS specific functionality.  But since you're apparently only coding for Windows, why even bother using Java?  I'd bet this is simplistic to do using .Net.

Comment: You're asking in essence how to make a Java Kiosk program, and I think that you may find solutions if you Google that term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works in an example for me.

with KeyEventDispatcher:

```
public class WindowsKey extends JPanel implements KeyEventDispatcher {
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
            int code = e.getKeyChar();

            if (KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS == code) {

                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

with KeyListener:

```
// Invoked when a key has been pressed.
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // Returns the integer code for the key on the keyboard and if
    // keyCode is equal to VK_WINDOWS)...
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS) {
        // ...call the doIT method.
        doIT();
    }
}
```

FYI:

```
/**
 * Constant for the Microsoft Windows "Windows" key.
 * It is used for both the left and right version of the key.  
 * @see #getKeyLocation()
 * @since 1.5
 */
public static final int VK_WINDOWS                  = 0x020C;
```

Comment: Thanks !! It is working with KeyListener upto certain extend. But NOT WORKING if I  continuously press the Start Button.